# Why can't backpropagation be used for binary threshold neurons

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation

I was reading that backpropagation can't be used for binary threshold neurons.

Binary threshold neurons calculate a cost using some weights, so why can't those weights be changed with backpropagation?

Comment: Is it differentiable? Back propagation requires that activation functions be differentiable.

Comment: It's a weighted sum of weights, no? So it is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, binary threshold neurons have piecewise constant activation functions such that the derivative of this activation function and thus the weight change is always zero (the undefined derivative at the step of this function is practically irrelevant).

If the step is approximated by a sigmoidal activation with a very large but finite slope, then backprop can theoretically be applied, but might converge very slowly.